# How to install GDAL and QGIS on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: gdal, linux, raspberry-pi

I would like to run GDAL QGIS on [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) to act as an affordable GIS processing engine.
The plan is to buy about 50 Pis.

**Does anybody have any links or information on installing and running GDAL on Raspberry Pi or just on installing GDAL in RASPBIAN environment?**

As best I can see Raspbian is my top choice and it is Debian based but ARCH, RASPBMC, PIDORA, RISC OS, and OPENELEC are the flavors of linux open to me out of the box.

Hopefully with Python.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu on the Pi along with QGIS

Comment: Thanks, that would be elegant. Do you any resources on this as I thought it was a work in progress and not finished? I do not see it listed as an official Pi distro. A webs search is not turning up much.

Comment: see https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/a-raspberry-pi-build-cluster-for-ubuntu

Comment: I'd be looking to confirm that GDAL can be built for ARM. (RPi runs ARM, not "x86"). It seems someone is 'trying' to build for Android (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingForAndroid), and from that you may infer it'll build to work on the Pi. This (dated) post (http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2009-March/020008.html) shows a lot of problems doing it. Maybe they've overcome the problem?

Comment: Maybe they figured it out - 2013: http://xastir.org/pipermail/xastir/2013-November/021862.html

Comment: Nice, i think no Gtiff may be a deal breaker though. This is straight on Raspbian right?

Comment: Mapperz- Thanks for the URL. the last post I can find from this project says it is still not working and they are having tech problems. This is from about 5 months ago. Ill use it 100% when they are finished but it is not yet operational as best as I can tell.

Comment: I can confirm that gdal will build and run on arm. Im not using it on raspberry pi, but on iOS, but arm all the same.

Comment: Hey for jobs that I just have running then it may work well with a handful of them.

Comment: Ok this is now working exceptionally well. Running a handful of systems at the moment mostly with gdal ogr functions. Cheap and cheerful.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Install [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/):

   - Download [NOOBS](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/)
   - Follow the [NOOBS Setup](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/) instructions.
2. Update Raspbian from its Debian wheezy base to Debian [jessie](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=47944&hilit=jessie+added+to+main+raspbian+archive&sid=1b68cb5637f77e09ad2bea4925bd9e3e):

   - `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` *# or use your favourite editor*
   - change all references of `wheezy` to `jessie`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get upgrade` *# this will take a long time, with occasional user prompts*
   - `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` *# this will take a **very** long time* …
3. Install qgis: `sudo apt-get install gdal-bin qgis`

This will install QGIS 2.2:
[image: QGIS running on Raspbian]

It's a bit slow, but seems to work as expected. Large geographic queries are pretty painful.

**Update**: It's just updated to 2.4 in Raspbian Jessie. It works.

Comment: Nice, Ill test early next week and give votes and returns

Comment: If you just want to run command-line gdal tools, stock Raspbian — installed with none of the palaver above — has GDAL 1.9.0 in the repositories. Finding and installing QGIS is harder.

Comment: 24 hours later, these instructions worked.

Comment: NOTE: Let it overwrite all the configuration files it wants! For the love of god just say yes! (serious problems here)

Comment: Does this also include qgis-mapserver? Tried to find binaries for ubuntu 14.0.4 for Raspberry PI 2 but failed (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qgis/2.4.0-1ubuntu1/+build/6997668).

Comment: Unlikely, but don't know for sure. Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 2 is in a *very* early state.

Comment: Ubuntu for Raspberry Pi 2 installed and worked like a charm. installed Xubuntu on it and it was smooth. A bit sluggish when running tomcat7 at the same time hehe...

Comment: got it running a rpi v2 http://mapperz.blogspot.com/2015/03/qgis-on-raspberry-pi-2.html using raspuntu arm7 call it testing but works well

Comment: Note that through jessie-backports you can even get qgis 2.8.1 . Debian GIS will try to keep this backport up to date with the 2.8 series.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [GDAL](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/g/gdal/) and [QGIS](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/q/qgis/) are part of the [Raspbian Repository](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository). So check that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file is configured, then try:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin qgis
```

I don't have a RPi, so I can't check if it works. You can try virtualise Raspbian with QEMU, so you can check it out yourself before making a large investment.

Comment: `E: Package 'qgis' has no installation candidate` on stock Raspbian …