# Pre-compiled GIS software for ARM architectures

Tags: ubuntugis, arm

I would like to install some GIS software on my ARM laptop; QGis in particular would be useful. On x86 architectures I install packages from the much useful [UbuntuGIS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGIS) repository. However, this repository only makes available [a restricted subset](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.osgeo.ubuntu/1178) of packages for ARM.

Is there any other source of pre-compiled GIS software for ARM architectures? Or must I compile the stuff myself?

Answer (score 6):

GDAL and QGIS have been [compiled by the DebianGIS team for Raspbian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116320/how-to-install-gdal-and-qgis-on-a-raspberry-pi) which is ARM architecture, and they can be installed from the Jessie suite on Raspbian.

You should be able to install Debian packages on your ARM Ubuntu, using `dpkg`.

A [search of the Debian Package Repository](https://packages.debian.org/search?&arch=arm&keywords=qgis) provides some builds of QGIS and GDAL for ARM*:

- [GDAL-BIN](https://packages.debian.org/stable/gdal-bin)
- [QGIS](https://packages.debian.org/stable/qgis)

*ARM64, ARMEL, ARMHF are supported.

Comment: I am not able to find these Raspbian packages [in the index](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/mainsearch?searchword=qgis&ordering=newest&searchphrase=all). From where can I obtain them? The Debian repo seems to have the same packages available from UbuntuGIS, which are mostly documentation.

Comment: @LuísdeSousa - I've added links directly to the packages on the Debian site, these have builds for ARM64, ARMEL and ARMHF, the Raspbi can use the latter two, I don't know if these are suitable for your hardware?  Unfortunately there don't seem to be builds available for ARM.

Comment: QGis fails to install with this error: "Dependency is not satisfiable: libqig-analysis2.4.0 (>= 2.0.1). I suspect I need to install a number of other packages by hand...