# Raspberry Pi3 model B and Qgis Version

Tags: qgis

I would like to install Qgis to my Raspberry and I would like to load some plugins in it.
I have some problems.
First on my pc I have installed the version 2.14.11 Essen of Qgis, instead on the raspberry the newest version of the Qgis that I have found is the 2.4 Chugiak. 
Why I cannot load in my raspberry the Essen Version?

Secondly I tried to load some plugin in my Raspberry. For Example I would like to load the QAD plugin but I have an error when I load it:
“’QsgBubberBand’ object has no attribute ‘setBorderColor’”.

Probably I missed something during the installation on my raspberry?

I tried also to install FirstAid Plugin and the error was:
"name “QgsPointLocator” is not defined"

Comment: What distro are you using?

Comment: Related no rpi binaries in armhf (above 2.14) https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222874/how-to-install-qgis-2-99-x-master-on-raspbian-gnu-linux-8-jessie.